# Is it possible to access PdfWriter or PdfContentByte when given iTextSharp.text.Document alone?

Tags: itext, pdf-writer

My question is exactly as the title says.

The reason I ask this question is that I need to workaround a wrong design. Simply speaking, my task is to implement the body of a callback function. The callback function receives a single argument of `iTextSharp.text.Document` and other non-iTextSharp data. The callback function will then add content (image, text, etc.) to the `Document`. It does not receive a `PdfWriter` or `PdfContentByte` argument. The callback function will not be able to ask its caller for anything else.

According to the Chapter 1.3.2 of the book "iText in Action", the `iTextSharp.text.Document` object allows one to add ***high-level objects*** to the PDF, whereas `PdfWriter` or its underlying `PdfContentByte` would be needed if anyone needs to add ***low-level content***.

The design mistake was that the previous software design requirement only specifies the need to add content which are covered by the high-level objects. Now the requirement has changed; I have to add low-level content as well. However, the callback interface was based on the previous requirement and was not changeable (due to semi-technical issues).

In particular, I have to apply `setRGBColorFillF` on some content. This is the reason I need access to the low-level writer.

My detailed question is therefore:

- Is it possible to access `PdfWriter` or `PdfContentByte` when given `iTextSharp.text.Document` alone?
- If no, is it possible to construct either `PdfWriter` or `PdfContentByte` separately (on a different document or stream), populate it with the content to be added, and then converted into a form that can be added back to the instance of `Document` that was given to the callback function?

From my reading of other Stackoverflow question, neither is possible. However, because of the difficulty for asking to change the interface, I thought it would be prudent for me to ask once again.

---

#### Remark 1.

(For those who insist on knowing the difficulty of changing the interface, the mis-designed interface is already in-the-wild, and therefore any future change means that clients using the previous interface will be missing the feature (the content that is added by the callback function) if the callback implementation requires a correctly-designed interface.)

---

#### Remark 2.

I am aware of the correct way to get the PdfContentByte, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932904/how-to-implement-getdirectcontent-itextsharp). I also blame myself for suggesting the wrong interface to another project team much earlier in the process without fully realizing what is meant in the five steps described in the Chapter 1.3 "Creating a PDF document in five steps".

Comment: Is the document really merely a Document or is it actually a PdfDocument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain some of the history of iText.

When I initially wrote iText, it was my intention to create a library that was able to create PDF documents and that allowed developers to create PDF without having to bother about PDF syntax.

To achieve this, I introduced the distinction between the `Document` class and the `PdfWriter` class. The `Document` class wasn't supposed to be aware that PDF was being created, it was only to be used to add content such as `Paragraph`s, `List`s, and other high-level objects for content. The `PdfWriter` was responsible for translating all this content into PDF.

However: PDF isn't a trivial document format, and I was faced with an annoying problem: if something went wrong during the creation of the PDF document, I ended up with an incomplete PDF file and it was very hard to debug such a file, because you often don't have a clue what caused the problem if you only have half of a PDF file.

So I also introduced an `HtmlWriter` (later on, other people also created an `RtfWriter`). The concept was simple: you would create a `Document` instance and you would attach one or more *listeners* to this `Document`. You could add one or more `PdfWriter` instances, one or more `HtmlWriter` instances, etc.

In recent versions of iText, `HtmlWriter` and `RtfWriter` have been removed from the library, but the concept remains: the *writer* listens to the *document*, and there is no way the document knows how many (if any) writer is listening.

This is the long version of my answer to your question.

The short version is *No, it is not possible to access a `PdfWriter` instance when you only have a `Document` instance.*